# Add new AcroForm field to a PDF

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, itext

I have used iText to fill data into existing AcroForm fields in a PDF.

I am now looking for a solution to add new AcroForm fields to a PDF. Is this possible with iText? If so, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is documented in the [official documentation](http://itextpdf.com/book), more specifically in the [SubmitForm](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=168) example. When using a tool such as iText, you should read the official documentation first ;-)

Anyway, I've written you a simple example called [AddField](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/acroforms/AddField). It adds a button field at a specific position defined by `new Rectangle(36, 700, 72, 730)`.

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws DocumentException, IOException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    PushbuttonField button = new PushbuttonField(
        stamper.getWriter(), new Rectangle(36, 700, 72, 730), "post");
    button.setText("POST");
    button.setBackgroundColor(new GrayColor(0.7f));
    button.setVisibility(PushbuttonField.VISIBLE_BUT_DOES_NOT_PRINT);
    PdfFormField submit = button.getField();
    submit.setAction(PdfAction.createSubmitForm(
        "http://itextpdf.com:8180/book/request", null,
        PdfAction.SUBMIT_HTML_FORMAT | PdfAction.SUBMIT_COORDINATES));
    stamper.addAnnotation(submit, 1);
    stamper.close();
}
```

}

As you can see, you need to create a `PdfFormField` object (using helper classes such as `PushbuttonField`, `TextField`,...) and then use `PdfStamper`'s `addAnnotation()` method to add the field to a specific page.